# Load a different theme for IE less than 9

Tags: themes

I want to load a different theme for those users who still use IE 6 - 7 - and 8
any plugin or code?

Comment: Don't forget to set `Cache-Control: private` because you have to break every other cache to make browser sniffing work. It would better tough just to learn CSS. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Drop this inside a plugin:

```
add_filter('template', function($template){

  // could be IE
  if(preg_match('/MSIE [1-9]/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    return 'your_ie_theme_name';

  // other
  return $template;

});
```

Just so you know, browser detection trough PHP is not really that accurate. There's a [`get_browser()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function available PHP, not sure if it's any better though.